# Colloquial term for "generous"

Tags: word-request

When an unsavory type, say a gangster or just your general low-life, acts in a generous way, how would you describe him/his action in order for the epithet to sound colloquial? Or at the very least how to stylize it to modern "thieve's dialect"?

For example:
The Guy likes to buy drinks for his buddies. His buddies think The Guy is "..." ?

Comment: "Peddler's French" is an obscure term for an obscure thing. It is the ancient "cant" used by thieves 200 or more years ago.  It doesn't mean modern slang.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: great. They think he's great. Guys don't go round saying other guys are generous.

Answer (score 1):

You could say he is a Robin Hood if he is generous to the poor and steals from the rich.

If you want to add some sarcasm you could say: He thinks he is a regular philanthropist doesn't he? Or some 'dialect' version of philanthropist.

Alternatively, a more sincere way to say it might be: he shares his good fortune.